# i am getting problem with ubuntu Lte 16.04 lib installation

Tags: grub2

what does it mean

E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Answer (score 0):

That error message means that some other file is using dpkg by locking the file `/var/lib/dpkg/lock`. You can see what process is locking it by running

`sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock`

It usually is an update checking utility. Once the process ends, the file will be unlocked and you can use dpkg again.